# JavaFX application to expose Webservice

Tags: java, android, web-services, javafx

I am new to Web service, and have a JavaFX desktop application running client-side.

I am planning to create an Android application that will call the web service exposed by the desktop application. Any suggestions on how to do this? Tutorial links would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you are new to webservices, but please go through some documentations first ! You may find a nice tutorial here

[A short introduction to Web Services](http://acs.lbl.gov/projects/gtg/projects/pyGridWare/doc/tutorial/html/x284.html)

Just to give you a brief idea on what is wrong with your question. `Javafx Desktop application and an android application are both basically clients` (who consume web servcies).

`You need to have a Server` (who exposes web services) `hosting a web application`, so that these clients can use it. Your webapplication build in java, php, asp etc. The language doesn't matter in case of webservices !